# Load the Link/URL in safari or chrome in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, google-chrome, safari

Hi everyone i had an application in the Appstore which was good for seven uploads but now the app has been rejected apple has asked us to move to enterprise application which i did but the problem is i want to navigate all the users to new app i had force update but the link was hard coded which takes the app to store but our client want to take all the users to that new page so i had a webview before login where am able to show the page the problem is webview is not able detect the downloads as the downloads will have only on safari or google chrome, so now i want an extension(safari/google) for the url which loads in the webview

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947892/downloading-a-file-using-web-view
Check this for downloading the content from webview.

Comment: Hit hanks for your now i can't edited as apple is not approving builds i want something like this googlechrome://google.com which open google something like this i want http://docs.google.com/gview?url=

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *url = @"some URL";

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] options: @{} completionHandler: nil];
```

Comment: Hit hanks for your now i can't edited as apple is not approving builds i want something like this googlechrome://google.com which open google something like this i want http://docs.google.com/gview?url=

Comment: you can add any link in that url but it will redirect the link in safari and if you find that answer useful then please tick the correct mark or upvote it

Answer (score 0):

```
if let link = URL(string: "itunes URL") {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(link)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(link)
        }
}
```

Comment: Hit hanks for your now i can't edited as apple is not approving builds i want something like this googlechrome://google.com which open google something like this i want http://docs.google.com/gview?url=